# Expanding a variable inside quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, bash-array

I am trying to get the files from S3 bucket,starting with certain prefix. To do so am using **aws cli** command in the bash script.

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash  

FILESIZE=$(mktemp)
declare -a files=( "A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0" "D3S0" "D4S0" "D5S0" "D6S0" )
for n in "${!files[@]}"; do
    printf '%8d  %s\n' "${n}" ${files[n]}
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '${files[n]}$(`date +%m%d`)')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}' >> "$FILESIZE"
#cat $FILESIZE
done
```

In my code there is a problem when expanding variables inside the quotes,  **$(`date +%m%d`)** Date variable is not expanding inside quotes.
So the output of the code should be like, only files arrived today which starts with the mentioned prefix    should come as a input.

```
   Error: command not found in the line  aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '${files[n]}$(`date +%m%d`)')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}' >> "$FILESIZE"
```

Can someone pls help me to expand the variables inside the quotes

Answer (score 2):

You have a double weird command substitution error:

instead of coding

```
$(`date +%m%d`)
```

you should only write:

```
$(date +%m%d)
```

The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g

```
foo=`command`
```

The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

### Test expanding variables

```
declare -a files=( "A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0" "D3S0" "D4S0" "D5S0" "D6S0" )
for n in "${!files[@]}"; do
    echo aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '${files[n]}$(date +%m%d)')]" 
done
```

### Output

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D1S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D2S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D3S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D4S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D5S00526')]
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query Contents[?contains(Key, 'D6S00526')]
```

The key contains the expanded date `0526`

Comment: I gave like `"Contents[?contains(Key, '${files[n]}$(date +%m%d)')]"` But when i print am not getting any output..files are present in S3. Instead of date command if i give `0525` am getting the output as expected

Comment: @clarie Where I am, the `date` command would output `0526` right now, not `0525`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, `0526` is correct...How can i expand date variable inside the quotes

Comment: Added test with expanded date

Comment: @ Gilles Quenot Thanks, but is there any can we excape the `'A1S00526'`single quotes...becoz in the S3 name is like `A1S00526`. Becoz of this single quotes output us null

Comment: ? Did you try to simply remove the single quotes ? `${files[n]}$(date +%m%d)` or you want `\'A1S00526\'` ? Try combinaisons

Comment: @ Gilles Quenot If i remove the single quotes, it is syntax error becoz aws s3api command syntax is like that,  and `\'A1S00526\'` did not work

Comment: @GillesQuenot Would the single quotes not kill the command execution too? `'${files[n]}$(date +%m%d)'` i.e. let $( go through without being interpreted? If not it has to be because they're also within double quotes and thus end up being escaped...

Comment: The test isn't sufficient to demonstrate that single quotes embraced with double quotes are OK ?